# android onSavedInstanceState saving and restoring time

Tags: java, android

A - What is the proper way to save a date/time for screen rotation

B - Why does my implementation below add 20 seconds to the saved time?

I am processing some calculations over time. I track the beginning of a specified period (abegtim date) and the end of a specified period (aendtim date). Each time I receive a new GPS reading from a GPS related service, aendtim is updated. I cannot allow screen rotation to reset my abegtim but that is what is happening. (string2date is my function)

I tested the code below on rotation and abegtim comes out of onRestoreInstanceState with a new time that is 20 seconds later than when it goes in to onSavedInstanceState .

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    savedInstanceState.putString("abegtim", date2string("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",abegtim));
    Log.e("savedinst B4 abegtim " + abegtim," ");
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    String strabegtim = " ";
    strabegtim = savedInstanceState.getString("abegtim", strabegtim);
    abegtim = string2date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",strabegtim);
    Log.e("savedinst AFTR abegtim " + abegtim," ");
}
```

E/savedinst B4 abegtim Tue Nov 22 08:20:16 PST 2016:
E/savedinst AFTR abegtim Tue Nov 22 08:20:36 PST 2016:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why this happens, but converting to a string sounds like overcomplicating the problem.

You can use the [timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) value of the Date object instead.

Assuming `abegtim` is of type `Date`:

```
long timestamp = abegtim.getTime();
```

and

```
abegtim = new Date(timestamp);
```

Also make sure that you don't override the value set by `onRestoreInstanceState` to `abegtim` with the default value (of now) in a later callback.
i.e., if you set the value of `abegtim` in your `onCreate` callback, make sure you only set it if `savedInstanceState` is null:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    abegtim = new Date();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Which data type in  "putDate" and :getDate" for onSavedInstance" will allow me put/save timestamp?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I can use putSerializable()
getSerializable() to put/get the date. thanks.

Comment: I used your approach. It fixed it. Thank.